# Is there any way to improve Phaser 2 Game performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, phaser-framework

I am using Phaser 2 in my game. When I open the game initially it works fine, with 55 to 60 fps, however after some time it slows to fps below 30. This is the url of game: http://139.59.91.216:8082/ .

**Game Area**

```
game = new Phaser.Game(1366, 778, Phaser.AUTO, null);
game.state.add('Game', Game);
game.state.start('Game');
glowFilter = new Phaser.Filter.Glow(game);
```

In the game's update function I am doing this:

```
update: function () {        
    // to update the stcik lenght 
    for (var i = self.game.snakes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        self.game.snakes[i].updateStick();
    }
    // to update the FoodGroup 
    for (var i = this.foodGroup.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var f = this.foodGroup.children[i];
        f.food.update();
    }

    updateAndSendData(self); // to send the data to server from client side
},
```

Can anyone suggest how I can improve the performance of the game?

Comment: What have you tried to improve the performance? What is in the update() and updateStick() functions? And have you tried without the glowfilter?

UPDATE: i have commented out your minimap code and was left with a perfect 60fps lock. Seems likely that something is wrong there.

Comment: @JensStragier - after research I got problem of loosing the fps. when I am playing game with small desktop resolution then it's working fine when playing on full desktop screen it loosing the fps.
I am  not able to find the problem. can you please help me find out the problem? and what is the solution of it?.